# Remove first name on in-text citation

Tags: biblatex, natbib

I am trying to sort out the citation and bibliography for a paper, and make it conform with the style-sheet from my university, which is a version of the Chicago style.

There are chicago-styles available both to Natbib and Biblatex, but I can't get any of the do do what I want:
Display only last name on "in-text" citation (unless there are many different authors with same last name), and then the full name in my bibliography.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4 paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[
authordate,
backend=biber,
natbib,
maxbibnames=99,
]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@BOOK{orton,
  title = {Survey of English Dialects},
  publisher = {Leeds: Arnold},
  year = {1962},
  author = {Orton, Harold},
  volume = {IV},
  date-added = {2014-04-20 12:50:04 +0000},
  date-modified = {2014-04-24 18:41:22 +0000}
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

This is a quote \citep{orton} .  And then the second quote by the same person     \citep{orton}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

As you can see if you try to run this, the in-text citation provides the full name like this (Orton, Harold 1962), while I simply want (Orton 1962). The bibliography looks fine.

John

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your MWE give me this for the in-text citation :

> This is a quote (Orton 1962) . And then the second quote by the same person (Orton 1962)

And in bibliography :

> Orton, Harold. 1962. Survey of English Dialects. Vol. IV. Leeds: Arnold.

Which is what you want, correct ? If this MWE give you the bad citation style, you probably should verify that you run the latest version of latex and its components ([How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution)).

If the MWE is working, you have to check your complete bib file and your other (and more complete) code. The issue is probably located in one of those files.